# Datetime and iso format

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

sometimes toString(datetime()) return the milliseconds without the leading zeros to reach the length of 3 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX). Is it a bug or normal behavior?

For example:

- 2019-11-21T15:59:22.**53**Z -> it should be 2019-11-21T15:59:22.**053**Z
- 2019-11-21T15:59:21.**216**Z -> OK
- 2019-11-21T15:30:09.**042**Z -> OK

This behavior causes an issue when I try to convert the string into a date.

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean trailing zero -no? (i.e. *2.53*) YOur example below has a leading zero *9.042*

Comment: I mean that sometimes the 0 is missing for millisecond minor than 100

Comment: why do you think it should be *...2.053* and not *...2.530*?

Comment: Because I guess that 530 will be returned correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [apoc.temporal.format](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/temporal/temporal-conversions/#temporal-conversions) function, specifying the [iso_instant](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:type-conversion:built-in) type conversion.

For example:

```
RETURN apoc.temporal.format(datetime("2019-11-21T22:04:19.13Z"), 'iso_instant');
```

will return:

```
"2019-11-21T22:04:19.130Z"
```

[UPDATE]

*Since the `TOSTRING()` function is not documented to return any particular ISO 8601 string format for a `datetime`, one should not depend on it returning a specific format -- or even returning the same string for the same `datetime` across versions.*

However, if you want a non-APOC approach that works with recent versions of neo4j (like, 3.5.12, on which this was tested), here is an example of one way to modify the current `TOSTRING()` output string to always have a 3-digit millisecond value:

```
// Generate a string.
// You can play with the number of digits after ".", and
// even eliminate the "." and any following digits.
WITH TOSTRING(datetime("2019-11-21T22:04:10.1Z")) AS d

// Always return a 3-digit millisecond time in result
WITH d, LENGTH(d) AS lth
RETURN d, CASE WHEN lth < 24
  THEN SUBSTRING(d, 0, lth-1) + SUBSTRING('.000Z', lth - 20)
  ELSE d END AS result
```

Comment: I'm finding a solution without apoc. Furthermore, I would like to know why toString(datetime()) has this behavior

Comment: The `TOSTRING()` function is not documented to return any particular ISO 8601 string format for a `datetime`, so you should not depend on it if you require a specific format.

Comment: So, is there no way to get a date in iso format without apoc?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show one workaround, but with a caveat.